# C# WMI runs an exe on a remote PC that then runs another exe on the same PC that then calls Directory.CreateDirectory on a network path and fails

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, directory-permissions

Using C# WMI I start an exe on another computer and this exe starts another exe using the C# `Process` class. The last exe tries to call `Directory.CreateDirectory` using a network path (aka `\\\\comp1\d$\dir\`). `Directory.CreateDirectory` throws this exception:

```
Access to the path '\\\\blah\blah\blah' is denied.   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, DirectorySecurity dirSecurity)
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path, DirectorySecurity directorySecurity)
```

If I run the third exe directly in a console on the computer it exists on this exception isn't thrown and everything works fine.

The security settings for the folder where the directory is being created has "Everyone" given full permissions.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you make sure that the shared network folder's security settings allows you read/write privileges?

Comment: Did you see @Nick's answer, below? My research in WMI tells me he has the correct answer. If you agree, you might want to select it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Also be aware that when launching an app via WMI, there is a third layer of rights. For instance, if you invoke a method on an existing WMI object, it may not delegate the callers rights, or even the rights of the host exe, but will have an Empty Principal. This may be happening to you.

Go to Computer Management, and under Services and Applications, right click on the WMI Control node and select Properties. Go to the Security Tab, and then navigate to the correct WMI Namespace (most likely root\CIMV2) and make sure the user you are using has the appropriate rights there as well.

Comment: If I added everyone to root\CIMV2 and gave it full permissions would that do the trick?

Comment: Possibly. I'm not exactly sure what's going on here. I just wanted to make you aware that when you are performing an action launched via WMI, you actually have a third set of permissions to deal with.

Comment: Right, thanks for the heads up. It's a painful situation for sure.

Comment: Nick is correct: WMI does not inherently send credentials to a process started on a remote host. Doing so would require the right "log on as other users", which is too dangerous. There is another method, though, created by Frank White. I reference his and created a full script here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11948096/1569434.

Answer (score 1):

As Aaron said, windows share security has two components The first is the security of the Share itself.  The second is the security on the files and folders in that share.

Both have to allow the create directory access in order for this to work.

You should also know that the EVERYONE group includes domain computer accounts, the built in system account, domain users, guest, and authenticated users.

This means that the first thing you want to do is see what user this is actually running under.  If it is running under the machine account AND it is not part of a domain then you will need to give that machine account access to the share and file system.

Answer (score 0):

See this thread for some suggestions about permissions.

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10058550/how-to-create-a-folder-in.aspx